# onCreateOptionsMenu called only for the selected fragment(item) inside view pager,( not called for left and right items of view pager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

There is a view pager and fragments as view pager items. Each fragment has its own tool bar. On calling set view pager adapter with ArrayList, onCreateOptionsMenu(onCreateOptionsMenu is inside fragment) is called only for selected(current selected item of view pager) item fragment, while left and right items of selected viewpager item(fragment) are also loaded but onCreateOptionsMenu is not called, hence menu items are not inflating for these fragments. 
- Is there a way to trigger onCreateOptionsMenu for each fragment?
- Is it possible to load only one items at a time in view pager?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding icons inside toolbar instead of inflating as menu.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/news_details_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="right">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/icon_comment"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/icon_share"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_comment"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to the pager, and in the `onPageSelected` function, call `invalidateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: Thanks, using this method onCreateOptionsMenu is getting called , but still not inflating menu in left and right items.